# How do I get input from user by using <button> and <input> in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, input

I want to create a form by using `<input>` and `<button>` like so:

[image]

I'm not sure how to pass the value I get from the text input field into a couple of functions on the frontend when I press the button "Send now". How do I make a `<form onSubmit={}>` without using forms, rather just an input field and a button?

This is what I've tried so far and it's not working, I'm not sure how to get the input value and pass it into the function like this `this.articleOnSubmit(*user input*)`. And also is the way i incorporated `onChange={this.articleOnChange}` correct? Here is my code:

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value }) => (
    <input
      placeholder={placeholder}
      type={type}
      step="0.0001"
      value={value}
      name={value}
    />
);

class Publish extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articleTitle: '',
    };
  }
 
  articleOnChange = (event) => {
    let title = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ articleTitle: title.toLowerCase() });
  }

  articleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    if (this.state.articleTitle) {
    console.log(this.state.articleTitle);
    this.hash(this.state.articleTitle)
      .then(hex => {console.log(hex); return hex;})
      .then(hex => this.addArticleHash(hex));
  
    event.preventDefault();
 }
  
  return (
   <Input placeholder="Article Name" name="article" type="text" onChange={this.articleOnChange} />
     <div/>
     {false
     ? (<Loader />)
     : (
     <button
     type="submit"
     onClick={this.articleOnSubmit(Input.name)}
     >
     Send now
     </button>
  )}
  </div>
 );
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you have to fix 2 issues here:

1. Since `Input` is a component, you have to get in its props the `onChange` prop you pass to it, otherwise it won't work.

```
const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, onChange }) => (
  <input
    onChange={onChange}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    step="0.0001"
    value={value}
    name={value}
  />
);
```

2. React `onClick` should be a function. Not a call. A function. What you did here was `onClick={this.articleOnSubmit(Input.name)}` - which is a call.

The solution is to change it into a function `() => this.articleOnSubmit(Input.name)`